# Homework help, how to find a base by given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I need to find a base from the polynomial space $P_3[x]$

for  $[1 − x + 3x^2 − x^3]_D = $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
    2\\
    0\\
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
$

If it helps, in the first part of the question I was asked to show that the following is true about the given space:

$B=\{1 + x, 1 − x, x^3 + x^2, x^2 − x^3\}$

$[1 − x + 3x^2 − x^3]_B = $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    1\\
    1\\
    2\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
$

and I found it was.

Can someone show me the full algebraic way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many bases in which $1-x+3x^2-x^3$ has co-ordinates $(1,0,2,0)$. One possibility is $\{1-x+x^2-x^3, x, x^2, x^3\}$.

Comment: yes, but is there an algebraic way to show how you got there?

Comment: Ok, here is an algorithm: (1) choose a vector $e_1$ that is not a scalar multiple of $v=1-x+3x^2-x^3$; (2) set $e_3 = \frac 1 2 (v-e_1)$; (3) choose $e_2$ that is not in the span of $\{e_1,e_3\}$; (4) choose $e_4$ that is not in the span of $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$. Then relative to basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3, e_4\}$ we have $v=(1,0,2,0)$.